# Pronouncing "ch"

Tags: pronunciation

Being new to german and not being used to it I find that 
Ich is pronounced as itch i.e the *the ch is pronounced like ch in chapter*
Milch is pronounced as *mil- sh*, ch as sh in shampoo
And Mich is pronounced as *mi-kh*, ch as kh in khaki
**Edit**
I have been using Duolingo,so this is the best I could guess on the basis of my listening skills. So correct me if I seem/ am wrong.
Is there no hard rule here on pronounciation and we always have to listen to the word from a native speaker and never guess the pronounciation as we do in Spanish / russian.

Comment: This is not at all true. The ch in Milch, mich, and ich are pronounced exactly the same.

Comment: It's helpful, thanks. @idmean

Comment: You can use the dict.cc online dictionary for listening to words being correctly pronounced by native speakers. --> https://www.dict.cc/?s=Milch   - Generally be aware that there are two different pronunciations of "ch" in German, depending on the preceding vowel: **dich** vs **Dach**, **mich** vs **doch**, **dicht** vs. **Docht**, etc., with the place in the mouth where the friction occurs being totally different. For the acoustical difference, use dict.cc.

Comment: Thanks, thats a helpful new experience as it is available in a lot more languages too. @Christian Geiselmann

Comment: Also be aware that the pronunciation changes from region to region. Many southern dialects pronounce the "ch" as "sh". Northern dialects (including Berlin) pronounce it as "kh" when used in the personal pronoun "Ich".

Comment: @Mr.Bum but these fellow se have explained above that ich in not ikh or ish but isch( sh with more of a sound from the throat).